# Заполнить фон изображением спрайта

Tags: css, css3

Как в css можно заполнить фон выбранным из общего спрайта изображением?

Comment: выбрать фон из спрайта `background-position` , а потом `background-repeat:repeat`?

Comment: Так не получается, фон заполняется всем спрайтом, а не отдельным изображением.

Comment: Ни как. Есть хак для Сафари `background: -webkit-canvas(canvasName)` и в канвасе уже можно рисовать что угодно. И есть хак дла FireFox `background: -moz-element(#element-id)` - соответственно в элемент можно вставить что угодно. Но это только 2 браузера и то не самых популярных. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3397334/use-canvas-as-a-css-background

Comment: @Dmitry, спасибо.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если повторение нужно только по одной из осей, то может помочь `border-image`:

```css
div {
  height: 200px;
  outline: 1px dotted red;
  position: relative;
}

div:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  z-index: -1;
  border-top: 64px solid;
  border-image: url(//www.gravatar.com/avatar/cbfaff96665b7567defe1b34a883db8b?s=256&d=identicon&r=PG) 64 64 0 round round;
}
```

```html
<div>Тут может быть тест</div>
<img src="//www.gravatar.com/avatar/cbfaff96665b7567defe1b34a883db8b?s=256&d=identicon&r=PG">
```

Answer (score 2):

В настоящее время средствами только CSS не получится.

Может если вставить картинку в svg, потом svg встроить как-то так `background-image: url('data:...')`... Но это уже изврат. Что-то мне кажется производительность браузера при этом будет хуже чем при отрисовке обычной картинки